# Raspberry Pi MySQL Remote Connection (error: 10061)

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, remote-access

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL server running on my Raspberry Pi 3 remotely (though on the same LAN).

Attempting to do so through HeidiSQL returns an error coded 10061. A bit of research suggests I have to edit the config to allow remote connections.

The config, however, does not contain a `bind-adress x.x.x.x` line (/etc/mysql/my.cnf) for my to comment out. Added it myself breaks the service, causing errors when trying to restart it.
Checking other possible config file locations resulted in only empty files.
Additionally, comparing to the "default" config file, mine is a lot shorter, and has no actual statements, other than a few includes for other config files (it seems). These included files are all empty as well.

I'm now lost, and cannot figure out how to allow remote connections to my server. Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: If that line isn't there and the solution is to comment it out, then don't add it just to comment it out. What is the full error coming back from HiediSQL (besides the number). This could be an issue with how your user is set up in the database.

Comment: @JNevill The complete error is: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (10061)".

I have tested with both the root user and a user-created user. Both are tested with "Host" set to "%" (wildcard), and also with the IP from which I am trying to connect to the database.

Comment: Two common problems. As you found out already: 1. MySQL has to listen/bind to all interfaces. Run `sudo netstat -ln | grep 3306` to verify. If you see `0.0.0.0:3306` it is setup to listen to all incoming network. If you see `127.0.0.1:3306` than it is only listening to localhost. If you see nothing at all, MySQL isn't started (correctly). 2. The firewall on your Pi, most likely IP-tables-based. Run `sudo iptables -L -n` to show its settings. Configuration depends on linux-distro and others (`firewall-cmd`, `csf`, ...) Can you update your question with both output?

Comment: @PetervanderWal This might be the problem. Running the `netstat` command gives me the following output:

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Which would suggest it only listens on the local host.

The `iptables` command returns: https://hastebin.com/lizipupoze.lisp

I hope this is the information you wanted, and thanks for the help. What are my next steps?

Comment: Did you really added `bind-address x.x.x.x` to my.cnf? That address should be `0.0.0.0`. Note the double `d`! And that setting should be within the `[mysqld]` group within that file. Otherwise, I don't know... can be some Linux-distro-flavor adding settings in a other location.

Comment: @PetervanderWal In my attempts, I've reinstalled mysql on the pi several times. Currently, I did not do anything to my.cnf other than check that the bind-address was not present. The config file contains no bind-adress statements.

Additionally, it should be noted that there is not [mysqld] designation/group in the config file. Might this be a problem?

Comment: Just to be sure, you see other groups within that file (like client, mysql, mysqladmin, mysqldump)? (Normally) you can safely add this group to that file. Putting the right setting in the right config group is important! The different groups are used for the different parts of th MySQL-suite (e.g. settings under `[client]` for the command line connection you can setup by typing `mysql` in your console)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PetervanderWal, I suspected that the lack of a `bind-address` statement in the config was no freak coincidence. Therefore, I did a grep search for any files containing "bind-address", and found the correct configuration file: `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`. This file had the ´bind-address´ statement, which - after commenting it out - fixed the problem.

The takeaway here (if you ask me) is, if none of your config files contain the `bind-address` statement, widen your search for the correct config file.

Thanks Peter, hope this helps others.